# How to get angular2 to work in eclipse with typescript

Tags: javascript, eclipse, typescript, angular

So I was starting researching about angular2 and since I saw so many references to typescript being prefered I am trying to switch to it from javascript. Problem is, I saw a nice little guide I could follow to install it all in eclipse (angular, javascript, everything needed to launch the 5 minute guide code on the main page of angular), so I did it and managed to get it to work.

Now I would like to do the same with typescript, but I find myself lost since it doesn't seem to be working, I can't launch code, it's like node.js isn't working anymore, but since I do not know what the expected result is, I am not sure what is missing.

For example, I re did the 5 minute guide and notice as a difference that I do not have the installation of the modules, nor any run-as configuration ready, in fact, I can't manage to run as any typescript code I try to do.

Comment: Have you tried VS Code?

Comment: No, I just heard about it today, so big coincidence you talked about it. It seems it's somewhat used frequently for this but I've been told licences are required, which I guess implies money. Have you used? Is it an improvement over other options and in what sense?

Comment: It's completely open source! And it's the best "IDE" for TypeScript, that I tried. Much better than the Eclipse plugin.

Comment: Oh, nice. I will check it then! I've checked 5 different options already so why not one more hehe. Thanks!

Comment: @monkeyintern: where did you find the 5 minute guide to setup angularjs with eclipse, I did not find it on angularjs site

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What I did was:

1- Install Eclipse Mars, other guys uses older versions

2- Install Node.js

3- Install WildFly Server

4- Install TypeScript plugin https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/typescript

5- Import my project in eclipse, you may have to create a new static web project and add your files in there. The 5 minute quick start is not an eclipse web project so you may not be able to import this. Do not forget to copy and past the same structure with the node modules that you have

6- Right click on the project > Configure > Enable Typescript Builder

7- Right Click the project > Properties > TypeScript > Compiler and configure as follows:

[image]

I hope this will do it for you.

Remember, this plugin does not respect json configuration file, so you have to do this manually as in the screenshot. Also, if you are going to provide arguments to your component constructor, You will have errors. Let me know if you got those. Another thing to mention is that using some annotations like @Input will not work, you will have to use inputs:[] inside your @Component annotation.

Comment: I wanted to thank you, this is working way better than the other plugin I had. Would you mind telling me how to "get" modules? When I did it with javascript, following the 5 minute tutorial, they were downloaded. Now, eclipse is complaining about almost any reference that "Cannot find module 'angular2/core'.", and I see people in other platforms where their package.json is not properly configured, but it should be in my case.

Comment: Allright I just remembered I have to do the run-as to the package.json so it does the npm install. I also created a new project as a static web project

Comment: I am missing a concept here, this probably requires another thread/question, but, now that I have the code and the modules, how would I go to run it and see it in a web browser and start watching what it actually does? When I was doing it with Javascript, I run as node applicaction in something called "lite-server", but with typescript it appears to be different?

Comment: Thanks you. Do you mind accepting this as a answer to the question?

Comment: Also, you should continue to get modules the same as you do usining npm. Make sure that you place them in the right place. You will still need the config files to do that.

Eclipse will still complain that it can not find the module, do not worry about that. It is THERE :). Just make sure to refresh the project in eclipse everytime after you use npm to get more modules. That way wildfly or your server will see the new files, but eclipse will still complain.

Comment: Yeah, I'm currently fighting the complain part. And I'm sorry I didn't accept earlier, since I do not have enough rep to upvote yet I guessed it would be the same for accepting and didn't try, my bad!

Comment: According to this thread that Eclipse plugin is no longer supported:  https://github.com/palantir/eclipse-typescript/issues/320

Comment: Why is wildfly server needed here?? Angular projects with node can run on node server right? Am i missing something?

Comment: You are absolutely right. This might be an answer for people who do not have a production node server and they build java application that serve their assets. Java apps will run under wildfly!

Answer (score 6):

You can try to add those plugins on top of Mars:

- https://github.com/angelozerr/angular2-eclipse
- https://github.com/angelozerr/typescript.java

Those 2 are incubating but already provide good features. There is another one, that I didn't try but which has some popularity:

- https://github.com/palantir/eclipse-typescript

Comment: What do you guys think about Eclipse Neon, the (now) newest version of Eclipse? Is it recommended using this IDE together with Angular 2?

Comment: Yes, Eclipse Neon has many improvement for JavaScript and family. Using Eclipse Neon + one of the plugins mentioned about is better than using Mars + same plugin.

Comment: typescript.java uses JSDT for syntax coloration, so if you use Eclipse Neon, you will have improvement for coloration (like ES6 import)

Comment: The one from Palantir is no longer being actively developed according to them...see the thread here:  https://github.com/palantir/eclipse-typescript/issues/320

Comment: If you use the Angular 2 Eclipse plugin, version 1.1 snapshot, you won't need any of the other TypeScript plugins, as the TypeScript core that comes with the Angular plugin works quite well. Tested in Neon.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse >= Neon

- `sudo npm install -g angular-cli` (`ng help` must work)
- See: https://github.com/angelozerr/angular2-eclipse
- Install it and restart Eclipse
- Open a `.ts` file

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse Oxygen

Default javascript installation, then added the default free plugin for angular 2 / typescript from here:

angular2.ide - http://oss.opensagres.fr/angular2-eclipse/1.3.0/

After installing I opened an existing Angular 4 / TS project, worked fine. I then installed support for .scss from http://www.liclipse.com/text/updates. All setup and configured with Typescript 2.4.1 / nodejs v6.9.4.

But within days it now fails to open .ts files at all. Re-installation of the ng plugin did not fix it, I uninstalled liclipse plugin and no change either. It basically leaves eclipse unusable for ng4 projects as is.

The logs show the following errors.

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Plug-in "ts.eclipse.ide.jsdt.ui" was unable to instantiate class "ts.eclipse.ide.jsdt.internal.ui.editor.TypeScriptEditor".
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.throwException(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
...
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/wst/jsdt/ui/text/JavaScriptSourceViewerConfiguration
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui (441).
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:529)
 ...
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Name index 1 in LocalVariableTable has bad constant type in class file org/eclipse/wst/jsdt/internal/core/JavaModelManager
```

Comment: It seems that JSDT and liclipse (which provides support for JavaScript too) is not compatible. I suggest you that you uninstall liclipse.

Answer (score -1):

I found 
`TypeEcs` plugin for Typescript

it provide below.

•Syntax highlighting

•Code Completion

•Code Outline

•Find References

•Rename / Refactor

•Open Type

•Code Compilation

•Format Code

•Comment Code

•Open Declaration

•Mark Occurences

•Type Script Debug