# Configure angular 2 project with maven and spring REST

Tags: node.js, eclipse, spring, maven, angular

I wanted to upgrade my small application from angular 1 to angular 2. I am somewhat new to angular 2 and node configurations. My web application use eclipse and maven. The problem is i could not able to configure using angular 2.

What directory structure should I use?

There are maven plugins available but i am bit confused about the directory structure of my angular 2 app.

Comment: I am currently working on the same thing but have a look at these answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35704973/how-to-configure-angular2-application-using-typescript-with-maven/35708519

Comment: if you don't have typescript up and running here is a good answer and the one I used http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35890887/how-to-get-angular2-to-work-in-eclipse-with-typescript

Comment: Thanks Charles. I followed these links but still i am unclear about directory structure and compilation. If there is any link which explains more it will be very helpful.

Comment: compilation? could you be more specific about what you plan on using such as which server, which plugins? Are you using plain old javascript or typescript to write your angular 2 code with?

Comment: I am using typescript. Also planning to use maven plugins.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Here from the angular site](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/style-guide.html#!#application-structure)
shows several demonstrations of how to structure an angular 2 project. In an eclipse maven web app I would start my client side files into the src/main/resources folder at the same level as the web-inf folder.

Maven pom.xml, include this into your project. Maven-fronted-plugin shouldn't be used for production. Maven will install two folders at the project root level with this setup, node and node_modules.

```
<build>
   <plugins>    
        <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install node and npm</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <nodeVersion>v5.3.0</nodeVersion>
                            <npmVersion>3.3.12</npmVersion>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>npm install</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <!-- Optional configuration which provides for running any npm command -->
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>install</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

package.json add this to the root level of the project before maven clean install.

```
{
  "name": "budget_calculator",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/compiler":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/core":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/http":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/upgrade":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.10",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi is this working for webpack and angualar 2 final release? thanks.

Answer (score 12):

Here is what I did:-

- Install Nodejs v6.9+
- Run **npm install @angular/cli –g** for Angular CLI
- Install Apache Maven or use any Maven friendly IDE
- Use your required Maven configuration, I used simple webapp (WAR).

**Directory Stucture** (Except for **ngapp** folder rest is standard Maven structure.)

```
ngfirst
├── pom.xml
├── src
│   └── main
│       ├── java
│       ├── resources
│       ├── webapp
│       └── ngapp
```

**Angular Part**

Open **ngapp** folder in terminal and type **ng init** command to initialize node and npm configuration, the result will be a simple Angular2 example application will the following directory structure inside ngapp folder:-

```
             ├── angular-cli.json
             ├── e2e
             ├── karma.conf.js
             ├── node_modules
             ├── package.json
             ├── protractor.conf.js
             ├── README.md
             ├── tslint.json
             ├── src
                 ├── app
                 ├── assets
                 ├── environments
                 ├── favicon.ico
                 ├── index.html
                 ├── main.ts
                 ├── polyfills.ts
                 ├── styles.css
                 ├── test.ts
                 └── tsconfig.json
```

This structure is Angular equivalent of Maven project structure and **src** directory is Angular Application's source, just like **maven build** command generates its output in **target** folder, **ng build** command generates its output in **dist** folder.

In order to package the generated Angular application within Maven generated WAR modify the build configuration to change the output folder from **dist** to **webapp**, open **angular-cli.json** file and modify its outDir as below:-

```
"outDir": "../webapp/ng"
```

At this point **ng build** command will generate built Angular Application inside **ng** directory of ngfirst/src/main/**webapp** folder.

**Maven Part**

Open pom.xml and configure following three maven plugins:-

1. **compiler-plugin**: No Java stuff to compile in /src/main/**ngapp** folder, exclude it.
2. **war-plugin**: /src/main/**ngapp** is Angular project folder and it should not be packaged in WAR, exclude it.
3. **exec-plugin**: Execute NPM Install and Angular-CLI Build commands to generate Angular Application in webapp folder for final packaging. Argument **--base-href** is required to load Angular resources from webapp's context path.

Here is how it should look like:-

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>ngapp/**</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>ngapp/**</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>exec-npm-install</id>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <workingDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/ngapp</workingDirectory>
                    <executable>npm</executable>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>install</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                    <goal>exec</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>exec-npm-ng-build</id>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <workingDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/ngapp</workingDirectory>
                    <executable>ng</executable>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>build</argument>
                        <argument>--base-href=/ngfirst/ng/</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                    <goal>exec</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

**Building Maven Project** (and Angular App too)

Open Terminal in project root folder **ngfirst** and run **mvn package** command, this will generate a WAR file (ngfirst.war) in **target** folder.

Deploy **ngfirst.war** in a container, open http://localhost:8080/ngfirst/ng/index.html in Browser. (adjust your hostname and port if required)

If everything went right, you should see **app works!** in browser, that is Angular Application at work!!

**JSP Pre-Processing**

We can leverage dynamic configuration and page rendering capabilities of JSP technology with Angular application, Angular SPA is served by the Java container as regular HTML page, **index.html** in this case, if we configure JSP Engine to pre-process html files too, then all JSP magic can be included inside Angular SPA Page, just include the following inside **web.xml**

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Save, rebuild maven project, deploy WAR and voila!!

Comment: If u have github link above project ..please post us .. its gonna help us ...@J_Dev

Comment: HI Dev, Can you please post github project link?