# how to integrate Angular 2 + Java Maven Web Application

Tags: java, web-applications, typescript, angular, maven-plugin

I have created a Angular 2 front-end Application.and i have created one Java Rest WS Back-end Application which is connected to DB.

My Folder structure for Angular 2 App is below-

```
Angular2App
  confg
  dist
  e2e
  node_modules
  public
  src
     app
     favicon.ico
     index.html
     main.ts
     system-config.ts
     tsconfig.json
     typings.d.ts
  tmp
  typings
  .editorconfig
  .gitignore
  angular-cli.json
  angular-cli-build.js
  package.json
  README.md
  tslint.json
  typings.json
```

And My Java Maven Web Application Structure is below-

```
JerseyWebApp
  src
   main
     java
       Custom Package
       java classes
     resources
     webapp
       WEB-INF
         web.xml
       index.html
  pom.xml
```

I want to know how to integrate these two applications into one application which will produce only one war file.

Comment: I build my application using spring boot and we jars for angular2. For sample refer https://github.com/Kiran-N/springboot-and-angular2

Comment: Had similar task, here is my approach http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37512154/configure-angular-2-project-with-maven-and-spring-rest/42283956#42283956

Answer (score 59):

Here is what I did:-

- Install Nodejs v6.9+
- Run **npm install @angular/cli –g** for Angular CLI
- Install Apache Maven or use any Maven friendly IDE
- Use your required Maven configuration, I used simple webapp (WAR).

**Directory Stucture** (Except for **ngapp** folder rest is standard Maven structure.)

```
ngfirst
├── pom.xml
├── src
│   └── main
│       ├── java
│       ├── resources
│       ├── webapp
│       └── ngapp
```

**Angular Part**

Open **ngapp** folder in terminal and type **ng init** command to initialize node and npm configuration, the result will be a simple Angular2 example application will the following directory structure inside ngapp folder:-

```
             ├── angular-cli.json
             ├── e2e
             ├── karma.conf.js
             ├── node_modules
             ├── package.json
             ├── protractor.conf.js
             ├── README.md
             ├── tslint.json
             ├── src
                 ├── app
                 ├── assets
                 ├── environments
                 ├── favicon.ico
                 ├── index.html
                 ├── main.ts
                 ├── polyfills.ts
                 ├── styles.css
                 ├── test.ts
                 └── tsconfig.json
```

This structure is Angular equivalent of Maven project structure and **src** directory is Angular Application's source, just like **maven build** command generates its output in **target** folder, **ng build** command generates its output in **dist** folder.

In order to package the generated Angular application within Maven generated WAR modify the build configuration to change the output folder from **dist** to **webapp**, open **angular-cli.json** file and modify its outDir as below:-

```
"outDir": "../webapp/ng"
```

At this point **ng build** command will generate built Angular Application inside **ng** directory of ngfirst/src/main/**webapp** folder.

**Maven Part**

Open pom.xml and configure following three maven plugins:-

1. **compiler-plugin**: No Java stuff to compile in /src/main/**ngapp** folder, exclude it.
2. **war-plugin**: /src/main/**ngapp** is Angular project folder and it should not be packaged in WAR, exclude it.
3. **exec-plugin**: Execute NPM Install and Angular-CLI Build commands to generate Angular Application in webapp folder for final packaging. Note --base-href argument, it is required to load Angular resources from webapp's context path.

Here is how it should look like:-

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>ngapp/**</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>ngapp/**</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>exec-npm-install</id>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <workingDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/ngapp</workingDirectory>
                    <executable>npm</executable>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>install</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                    <goal>exec</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>exec-npm-ng-build</id>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <workingDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/ngapp</workingDirectory>
                    <executable>ng</executable>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>build</argument>
                        <argument>--base-href=/ngfirst/ng/</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                    <goal>exec</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

**Building Maven Project** (and Angular App too)

Open Terminal in project root folder **ngfirst** and run **mvn package** command, this will generate a WAR file (ngfirst.war) in **target** folder.

Deploy **ngfirst.war** in a container, open http://localhost:8080/ngfirst/ng/index.html in Browser. (adjust your hostname and port if required)

If everything went right, you should see **app works!** in browser, that is Angular Application at work!!

**JSP Pre-Processing**

We can leverage dynamic configuration and page rendering capabilities of JSP technology with Angular application, Angular SPA is served by the Java container as regular HTML page, **index.html** in this case, if we configure JSP Engine to pre-process html files too, then all JSP magic can be included inside Angular SPA Page, just include the following inside **web.xml**

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Save, rebuild maven project, deploy WAR and voila!!

Comment: I'd recommend to use `<warSourceExcludes>ngapp/**</warSourceExcludes>`to exclude ngapp folder or `packagingExcludes>`

Comment: @J_Dev this works fine.the problem is jar includes Node modules also.how can i only includes `ng serve --prod` or `ng build` output ?

Comment: @J_Dev - Can you please explain why are you excluding ngapp from the war. I thought this question is about integrating/bundling the angular 2 app and java code in the same war. If you are excluding it then how does the angular code get deploy?

Comment: don't you need url rewriting for angular routers?

Comment: @user911 Directory `ngapp` (the sources of the Angular app) is excluded from the war, but directory `webapp/ng` (the executable of the Angular app) is included in the war.

Answer (score 13):

My side I have a maven module for angular sources called **prj-angular**, and anoter one for war application called **prj-war**.

first **prj angular** is built:

- it uses maven-exec-plugin to call `npm install` and `ng build` (thanks to @J_Dev!)
- change resource default directory to `dist/`
- skip jar MANIFEST generation
- maven module result: a jar with generated angular **dist/** content only!

then, second **prj_war** is build:

- has **prj angular** as dependency
- use unpack phase to unzip the previous jar into web app destination
- this module build you app war with fresh angular dist.

Follow under the corresponding plugin configuration I used:

**prj angular (pom.xml extract)**

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>dist</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <!-- skip compile -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-compile</id>
                    <phase />
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>exec-npm-install</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <workingDirectory>${project.basedir}</workingDirectory>
                        <executable>npm.cmd</executable>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>install</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>exec-npm-ng-build</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <workingDirectory>${project.basedir}/src</workingDirectory>
                        <executable>ng.cmd</executable>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>build</argument>
                            <argument>--no-progress</argument>
                            <argument>--base-href=/app/ng/</argument> <== to update
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>false</addClasspath>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**prj war (pom.xml extract)**

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unpack angular distribution</id>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>com.myapp</groupId> <== to update
                                <artifactId>prj-angular</artifactId> <== to update
                                <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                                <includes>**/*</includes>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/prjwar/ng</outputDirectory> <== to update
                        <overWriteReleases>true</overWriteReleases>
                        <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: recently I discovered https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin

Answer (score 8):

Funnily enough, I did just this last week!

> Using Netbeans 8.1 and a Tomcat servlet version 8.0.27

Angular and Java project file structure.

Java Project is called Foo. Angular Project is Bar

```
Foo (Java Maven Project)
|__ src
|    |__ main
|    |    |__ webapp (This folder contains the entire Angular Project)
|    |    |    |__ META-INF
|    |    |    |    \__ context.xml 
|    |    |    |__ WEB-INF
|    |    |    |    \__ web.xml
|    |    |    |__ includes
|    |    |    |    |__ css
|    |    |    |    |__ images
|    |    |    |    \__ js
|    |    |    |
|    |    |    | ## Bar project files are located here ##
|    |    |    |
|    |    |    |__ app
|    |    |    |    \__ All .ts and compiled .js files are located here
|    |    |    |__ node_modules
|    |    |    |    \__ any dependencies used for Bar are located here
|    |    |    |__ typings
|    |    |    |    \__ typings for Typescript located here
|    |    |    |
|    |    |    |__ README.txt
|    |    |    |__ index.jsp
|    |    |    |__ package.json
|    |    |    |__ systemjs.config.js
|    |    |    |__ tsconfig.json
|    |    |    |__ typings.json
|    |    |    \ ## Bar project files end here
|    |    | 
|    |    |__ resources
|    |    |    |__META-INF
|    |    |    |    \__ persistence.xml
|    |    |__ java
|    |    |    |__ hibernate.cfg.xml
|    |    |    |__ com
|    |    |    |    |__ orgName
|    |    |    |    |    |__ packageName
|    |    |    |    |    |    \__ .java files are here
|__ pom.xml
\__ nb-configuration.xml
```

Comment: I think this is bad approach cause you put everything into webapp not just what ng build preapres. Your webapp has the node_modules/* and is causing your webapp size to explode. I discourage everyone to use this approach. The only thing in webbapp folder should be what ng build creates in your build/ or dist/ folder

Answer (score 3):

I recommend let the two applications separated, this way you have modularity.
This way you can change the Angular App without affect your service, and vice versa. For second, your apache/nginx are faster to deliver your js and html from Angular instead Tomcat (for example). But if you still want put the Angular application inside the war, the pattern is that all web resources are in src/main/webapp.

Comment: That way I tried actually putting all the web resource under src/main/webapp, but here i facing one problem like angular2 is built on typescript,so tomcat server not able to compile those files.And the application stuck.

Comment: it's right.. maybe this can help you then:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/37398298/2285259

Answer (score 2):

I want to share how I set my Angular/Java projects. Some important things:

1. There's only a single Maven project and it allows me to build the entire project. In this way, I can build the entire project or build client and backend separately.
2. My project is based on Spring Boot framework. However, you can easily adapt my solution to your situation. I generate the `output` code of Angular project is put under the `META-INF' folder. You can obviously change it if you don't use Spring Boot.
3. In my project, I want to publish the angular project in the `public` folder.
4. When I develop, I run the Angular project and the backend project separately: Angular with `ng serve` and the backend project (the Java part) in the IDE (Eclipse).

Ok, let's start. The entire project structure is represented in the following picture.

[image: Project structure]

As you can see, I put the Angular project in the 'src\main\ngapp' folder. For the Java project (the backend) I used Eclipse IDE, for the Angular project I used Webstorm. You can choose your preferred IDE to manage the project. The important thing: you will need two IDE to manage the entire project.

To build the Angular project with Maven, I used the following maven profile definition.

```xml
<profile>
    <id>build-client</id>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <nodeVersion>v10.13.0</nodeVersion>
                    <npmVersion>6.4.1</npmVersion>
                    <workingDirectory>src/main/ngapp/</workingDirectory>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install node and npm</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm install</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm run build-prod</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>run build</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>prod</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>run-script build</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

As you can see, I used the `com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin` plugin to install node and run npm to build the Angular project. In this way, when I run the maven profile `build-client` The plugin is used to:

- Check and install, if it is needed, the node version `v10.13.0` in the Angular project folder `src/main/ngapp/`
- Run the command `npm run build`. In the Angular project is defined the build alias in the `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    "build": "ng build --configuration=production",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
}
```

The Angular client must be place in `public` folder of the web application. To do this, the Angular project is configured to have the `baseHref=/public`. Moreover, the builded project must be place in `src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/public`. In `angular.json` you will find:

```
"build": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
  "options": {
    "baseHref":"/public/",
    "outputPath": "../resources/META-INF/resources/public",
    ...
```

In a no-Spring Boot project you probably need to put the builded angular project directly in `src/main/webapp/public` folder. To do this, just modify the `angular.json` file as you need.

You can find all the project's code in [my github project](https://github.com/xcesco/files-on-cloud). The plugin project is [here](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin).

Comment: I have a question about your deployment. Are you running into routing issues/ Maven? If you enter something in the url that doesn't point to /public, (ie /public/user) do you get a while list error page?   It looks like our project is setup similar to yours. Both apps deploy separately under Maven , one for java one for angular. Then its configured to serve the angular app as a static page.

Answer (score 1):

Solution based on command line building of angular project with

```
npm install --verbose
npm run ng build
```

**given**

```
src/main/frontend
src/main/webapp
```

**maven-war-plugin + exec-maven-plugin**

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
        <configuration>
            <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            <webResources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/frontend/dist</directory>
                </resource>
            </webResources>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>npm-install</id>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <workingDirectory>src/main/frontend</workingDirectory>
                    <executable>npm</executable>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>install</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                    <goal>exec</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>npm-ng-build</id>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <workingDirectory>src/main/frontend</workingDirectory>
                    <executable>npm</executable>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>run</argument>
                        <argument>ng</argument>
                        <argument>build</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                    <goal>exec</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

**maven-war-plugin + maven-antrun-plugin** (failed to run npm directly on my machine, hence OS dependent build)

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
        <configuration>
            <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            <webResources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/frontend/dist</directory>
                </resource>
            </webResources>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>exec-gen-sources</id>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <target name="Build Frontend">
                        <exec executable="cmd" dir="src/main/frontend" failonerror="true">
                            <arg line="/c npm install --verbose" />
                        </exec>
                        <exec executable="cmd" dir="src/main/frontend" failonerror="true">
                            <arg line="/c npm run ng build" />
                        </exec>
                    </target>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                    <goal>run</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<plugin>
                        <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                        <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.3</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <nodeVersion>v10.13.0</nodeVersion>
                            <npmVersion>6.4.1</npmVersion>
                            <workingDirectory>src/main/ngapp/</workingDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>install node and npm</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>npm install</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>npm</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>npm run build-prod</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>npm</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <arguments>run build</arguments>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>prod</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>npm</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <arguments>run-script build</arguments>
                                </configuration>
                                <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
```

Comment: Welcome to S/O. Please include a brief explanation of what you're doing when giving an answer.