# Angular2 typescript POST request

Tags: angular, typescript, http-post

I'm testing this sample: http://plnkr.co/edit/WTu5G9db3p4pKzs0WvW6?p=preview.

This code, implements a login form with name, mail, profile. On clicking submit button, an alert appears on display with name and email fields.

```
saveUser() {
    if (this.userForm.dirty && this.userForm.valid) {
        alert(`Name: ${this.userForm.value.name} Email: ${this.userForm.value.email}`);
    }
}
```

On above, the saveUser function in `app.component.ts`. It executes the alert on clicking button. On saveUser function, I would like to invoke a POST request. How can I do it?

Comment: You need to have a container running your servlet and then make a http request (probably POST) to the url of that servlet.

Comment: [Angular2 HTTP Client](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#update)

Comment: I use eclipse neon with apache tomcat server v9.0

Answer (score 0):

You can save Users by calling the service( using `POST` request) like in below **sample**.

```
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
this.http.post('http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/poc-post/', 
                       JSON.stringify({firstName:'Joe',lastName:'Smith'}),
                       {headers:headers})
.map((res: Response) => res.json())
.subscribe((res:Person) => this.postResponse = res);
```

Answer (score 0):

@Nitzan is correct in that there needs to be a servlet already running by the time you make the POST call.

I have been working on a project that involves an Angular2 front-end and a Java RESTful service for the back end. You can see how it is structured my answer to this question: [how to integrate Angular 2 + Java Maven Web Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38532210/how-to-integrate-angular-js-2-java-maven-web-application/38831642#38831642)

For my project, I start the tomcat servlet (version 8.0.27) inside of netbeans, which also serves my app. This ensures that there is a server listening for specific requests made by the app, when the user gets to that point.

## Code snippets

> data.service.ts

## Most of this .ts file came from the [Angular Developer guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#update), credit goes to the author of that.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
    constructor (private http: Http) {} // Inject Http client Service
    private baseListUrl: string = 'bar/request?id=';

    sendInput (input: string) {
        let uInput = JSON.stringify({input});
        let header = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'MIMETYPE/HERE'});
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers});

        this.http.post(this.baseListUrl.concat(input), uInput, options)
                        .map(this.extractData)
                        .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private extractData(res: Response) {
        let body = res.json();
        // alert("body: " + body);
        return body.docs || {};
    }

    private handleError (error: any) {
        // In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure
        // We'd also dig deeper into the error to get a better message
        let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
          error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
        console.error(errMsg); // log to console instead
        return Observable.throw(errMsg);
    }
}
```

> foo.java

```
@Path("bar")
public class Baz{

    @POST
    @Path("/request")
    @Consumes(Mediatype.MIMETYPE_HERE)
    public Response doWhatYouNeed(string input) {
        // I don't have the exact code for you, but this should serve as a good starting point.
    }
}
```