# maven build angular project in maven with com.github.eirslett does nothing

Tags: maven

My project structure is like this:

```
demo-welcome
 +-- pom.xml
 +-- package.json
 +-- src
 |  +-- files
 +-- dist
 |  +-- files
```

What I want to achieve is that in the build phase of maven I get a target that generates my dist folder with the final results.

So I was reading this example: 
[build angular 2 project in maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39585612/build-angular-2-project-in-maven)

I have in my package.json

```
"scripts": {
  "ng": "ng",
  "start": "ng serve",
  "build": "ng build --prod",
  "test": "ng test",
  "lint": "ng lint",
  "e2e": "ng e2e"
},
```

then my pom.xml looks like this:

```
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
     <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
     <groupId>com.denv</groupId>
     <artifactId>demo-welcome</artifactId>
     <packaging>war</packaging>
     <version>1.0</version>
     <name>Welcome Page for Demo</name>
     <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
     <build>
        <finalName>demo-welcome</finalName>
        <pluginManagement>
           <plugins>
              <plugin>
                  <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                  <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                  <executions>
                    <execution>
                      <id>ng build</id>
                      <goals>
                          <goal>npm</goal>
                      </goals>
                      <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                      <configuration>
                          <arguments>run build</arguments>
                      </configuration>
                    </execution>
                  </executions>
              </plugin>
              <plugin>
                 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                 <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                 <configuration>
                    <webXml>WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                    <webResources>
                       <resource>
                          <directory>dist</directory>
                       </resource>
                    </webResources>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                 </configuration>
                 <executions>
                   <execution>
                     <phase>package</phase>
                   </execution>
                 </executions>
              </plugin>
           </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
     </build>
  </project>
```

My idea was to have NPM build create my dist folder and then just package it

but it seems the frontend-maven-plugin never really runs and I don't understand why.

This is the output

```
$ mvn clean package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Welcome Page for Sales 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ demo-welcome ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\dev\repo\bitbucket\denv\denv-ccp\demo-welcome\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ demo-welcome ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\dev\repo\bitbucket\denv\denv-ccp\demo-welcome\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ demo-welcome ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ demo-welcome ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\dev\repo\bitbucket\denv\denv-ccp\demo-welcome\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ demo-welcome ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ demo-welcome ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) @ demo-welcome ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [demo-welcome] in [C:\dev\repo\bitbucket\denv\denv-ccp\demo-welcome\target\demo-welcome]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp webResources [C:\dev\repo\bitbucket\denv\denv-ccp\demo-welcome\dist] to [C:\dev\repo\bitbucket\denv\denv-ccp\demo-welcome\target\demo-welcome]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.052 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-03-02T12:38:11+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/245M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) on project demo-welcome: Execution default-war of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2:war failed: basedir C:\dev\repo\bitbucket\denv\denv-ccp\demo-welcome\dist does not exist -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

I also tried to run delete all plugins from the pom and run only the frontend-maven-plugin but it seems to do nothing related to it and even though it doesn't fail it does not do anything.

```
$ mvn clean package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Welcome Page for Sales 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ demo-welcome ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\dev\repo\bitbucket\denv\denv-ccp\demo-welcome\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ demo-welcome ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\dev\repo\bitbucket\denv\denv-ccp\demo-welcome\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ demo-welcome ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ demo-welcome ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\dev\repo\bitbucket\denv\denv-ccp\demo-welcome\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ demo-welcome ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ demo-welcome ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ demo-welcome ---
[WARNING] JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion!
[INFO] Building jar: C:\dev\repo\bitbucket\denv\denv-ccp\demo-welcome\target\demo-welcome.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 9.329 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-03-02T12:45:03+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/205M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I have the same problem with a React project! It happens only sometimes, though, and it goes away by running two consecutive Maven builds. I guess it's something to do with caches and cleanups