# Run AngularJS template project on Wildfly10.x in Eclipse

Tags: java, angularjs, eclipse, jboss, wildfly

I have Bootstrap Admin Template including AngularJS and I have run it with gulp, but my question is how can i run it on Wildfly 10.x with Java Web Application project that I already have and to show the Angular template project in browser?

When I import the folder with the template in Web Content of my java web app project in eclipse, it wont load .css files and it can't recognize any angular controller.

To be more precisely, I want to import Angular template project in my Java Web App project and run it on WildFly 10.x server

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38532210/how-to-integrate-angular-2-java-maven-web-application