# Can We use Java EE Servlets for the backend with Angular as the frontend?

Tags: java, angular, servlets

I was wondering if it is possible to use Angular(2+) as the frontend, and use specifically Java EE Servlets as the Backend? If so, can the project be stored as a WAR file?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes. You can put any front-end library in front of  any backend web application. Some just harder to integrate than others

Comment: Front end is 100% abstracted from the server. You can use anything with anything

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible wiht JEE servlets with angular2+ as a front end.

You can create the angular project using angular cli. Go through the following link,

[`Connecting your Angular 2 App to your Java EE Backend`][1]

For creating angular project you can

From the Eclipse menu, choose **`File>New>Dynamic Web Project`**; or right click in Project/Package Explorer and choose **`New>Dynamic Web Project.`**

**`Initialize using angular cli`**

Right-click the newly created project and select Show in>Terminal. and type **`ng init`** , after that you can run **`npm start`** and see running your application.

Comment: Thank you, could you tell me if it's possible to store the project in a single WAR file?

Comment: @AbhishekGangadhar yes possible https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45915379/how-to-setup-angular-4-inside-a-java-war-project

Comment: @Sajeetharan can you please add more information to the answer? You should know by now this answer is useless if that link dies or moves.

Comment: @SterlingArcher added the info