# Angular7 + maven with IBM websphere error (frontend-maven-plugin:1.0:npm (npm install fail))

Tags: java, angular, maven, websphere

I have a complete angular7 project and want to integrate with java.
is there any way to do it?

I am using eclipse maven + ibm websphere. (not spring boot)

I referred [this  post(by @TimeTraveler)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45915379/how-to-setup-angular-4-inside-a-maven-based-java-war-project) and tried to follow...
however when I run command  **mvn clean package**, I encounter this error

```
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.0:npm (npm install) @ angular7test ---
[INFO] Running 'npm install' in C:\Users\eclipse-workspace\angular7test\angular-project
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  02:01 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-11-29T23:16:03+08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.0:npm (npm install) on project angular7test: Failed to run task: 'npm install' failed. java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Users\eclipse-workspace\angular7test\node_installation\node\node.exe" (in directory "C:\Users\eclipse-workspace\angular7test\angular-project"): CreateProcess error=267, The directory name is invalid -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

and I also have a question .. based on [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45915379/how-to-setup-angular-4-inside-a-maven-based-java-war-project), maven project looks like below

- Maven Project -
- src

  - main
  - java
  - resources
  - webapp

    - WEB-INF
    - web.xml
- angular-project (I paste my angular project here)
- ***node_installation***  ========>what is this?????
- pom.xml

what is node_installation? .. is that a folder? do i need to create?

this is my package..
[image]

Comment: What about that answer is unclear to you? And what errors are you getting? There really isn't a difference between Angular 2+ versions when it comes to deploying them in a war, as far as I know...

Comment: @lwestby hi, Please check my update..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you posted indicates that Maven can't find the node.js executable `node.exe` in order to build your Angular project. Make sure you configure your pom as indicated on the [frontend-maven-plugin readme page](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin#installing-node-and-npm) so that it will install node and npm into your project dir where maven expects to find it. This will create the node_installation directory you are missing and populate it with the `node.exe` executable, which should resolve the error.

Comment: thanks.. i resolved posted error. however i encounter new one... which is [l (npm build) on project angular7test: Failed to run task: 'npm run build' failed. org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error:] do you have any idea on this...?

Comment: Sounds like npm itself failed. Scroll up in your logs a bit and look for other errors coming directly from npm