# Failed to load resource error when starting Spring-Boot Application with Angular 7 Frontend (missing resources)

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

I want to build a Spring-Boot-Application with Angular frontend. So I used the Spring-Boot-Initializer to build up a project and added a `RestController` for `/greet/world`. Then I created a new Angular-Project in my `src/main`-folder by executing `ng new ui` (including `routing` and `css`).

I updated the `output-Path` in my `angular.json` to the following:

```
"outputPath": "../resources/static"
```

Then I added the `Http-Get`-Request in my `app.component.ts` and ran the following commands to build the `jar`:

- `ng build --prod` from my src/main/ui
- `cd %back_to_project_root%`
- `mvn clean package`
- `cd target`
- `java -jar Jar-file`

When opening `http://localhost:8080` I see the usual Angular-Startup-Page and the following console-log:

[image: The console log]

What did I do wrong when including my frontend into the backend? Running `ng serve` from my `src/main/ui` works perfectly fine.

**My `app.component.ts`:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'ui';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/greet/world').subscribe( (data) => {
    console.log('DATA', data);
      this.title = 'try';
    });
  }

}
```

**My HelloWorldController.java**
package com.demo.example.controller;

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/world")
    public String greetWorld() {
        return "Hello world";
    }

}
```

**My pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.hud</groupId>
    <artifactId>HelloWorld</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>HelloWorld</name>
    <description></description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>ng</executable>
                    <workingDirectory>src/main/ui</workingDirectory>
                    <argument>
                        <argument>build</argument>
                    </argument>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Edit 1**

I changed my output-path to `../../../target/static` and then ran `mvn clean package` and `ng build --prod` afterwards.

Yet, this does not really save the day since these are not provided in the `jar`-file when running `mvn clean package`, but it solved the question for the moment.

**Edit 2**

I reworked my code like suggested and got the following stuff:

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>HelloWorld</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>HelloWorld</name>
    <description></description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm install</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>install</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm build</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>run build</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                </executions>
                <configuration>
                        <nodeVersion>v10.14.1</nodeVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                            <!-- It must match the resulting war-file name -->
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}/</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${project.basedir}/dist</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

When executing `mvn clean install` from project-root I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.6:npm (npm install) on project HelloWorld: Failed to run task: 'npm install' failed. 
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "c:\Dev\wsp_test\HelloWorld\node\node.exe" (in directory "c:\Dev\wsp_test\HelloWorld"): CreateProcess error=2, System cannot find the file (<- this is translated, so might be different wording)-> [Help 1]
```

Comment: Your controller mapping is for `/hello/world`, not `/greet/world`.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas you are right, what a stupid mistake... thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Open your `angular.json` file, set `"outputPath"` to `../../../dist`
- In your `package.json`, you should have a `build` script, example:

```
"scripts": {
   [..]
   "build": "ng build --prod",
}
```

- Edit your `pom.xml` to add the `frontend-maven-plugin` plugin to build angular with maven, and `maven-resources-plugin` to copy them ([How to setup angular 4 inside a maven based java war project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45915379/how-to-setup-angular-4-inside-a-maven-based-java-war-project))
  :

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
            <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>install node and npm</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>npm install</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>install</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>npm build</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>run build</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <configuration>
                    <nodeVersion>v8.9.0</nodeVersion>
                </configuration>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-copy-resources</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                        <!-- It must match the resulting war-file name -->
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}/</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${project.basedir}/dist</directory>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: The usual Path where the static assets are located is in `src/main/resources/static` (as far as I know). My current output-Path is configured: `"outputPath": "../resources/static",` since my angular root is in `src/main/ui` (so when executing `mvn package` I am executing `ng build` from `src/main/ui` and throw the output into `src/main/resources/static`. The app is displayed, so this seems to work out properly. I just had some problems with routing when the page is reloaded lately. This comes to the error I mentioned above.

Comment: Can you share the java code that configures the angular static assets path ?

Comment: I am not completely sure if I understand that right, so let me try to clarify what I should provide: There is a static directory for static resources. Since my Application is a Spring-Boot Application with Angular frontend, that directory is `src/main/resources/static` (by default I guess?). So I need to ensure my `ng build`-output is placed in that directory, Spring-Boot and/or Maven are doing the rest for me, right (or did I missunderstand that?). So you want me to provide what throws my Angular into `static`-folder? Or what executes `ng build`?

Comment: I updated my Post and provided an reproduceable description of what I am doing/tried to do

Comment: Yes it worked and I have no idea why it worked or what I did differently, yet I tried with a new project and also my `pom.xml` did not work any more, so I did something wrong probably. In edit I tried from scratch and had the same error (also by building manually and not with `pom.xml`).

Comment: Try to set the "outputPath" to "../../../target/static", and do an `ng build` after `mvn clean package`

Comment: That looks good, sadly when I run the `pom.xml` I adjusted just like you mentioned (and then running `mvn clean install`) I got the following error:  `Cannot run program %Project_Dir%\node\node.exe (..)` pointing the a relative path from project dir (`node/node.exe`) where node is certainly not installed. Did you do anything else on that?

Comment: I added the node configuration

Comment: I edited the question again (see edit 2) to clarify what happens for me

Comment: Check the `install node and npm` execution config added to the pom.xml

Comment: That should be installing node and npm in a project directory, right? Can I also provide my default installation directory (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe) for that?

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately you can't set an absolute path for node (but you can customize the local install directory), from the docs: https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin#installing-node-and-npm