# Error while creating war using Maven and NgXCreditCardsModule

Tags: angular, angular6, credit-card

I am using the NgXCreditCardsModule for the credit card validation in my angular6 application and I was able to use it through ng serve. But when I tried to build the war file using `maven` I am getting below error:

```
ERROR in : Unexpected value 'NgXCreditCardsModule in C:/Users/infouser/git/branches/Orion-App/orion-ui/node_modules/ngx-credit-cards/index.js' imported by the module 'PaypalPaymentModule in C:/Users/infouser/git/branches/Orion-App/orion-ui/src/app/modules/paypal-payment/paypal-payment.module.ts'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.
```

I am attaching the code of my angular module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { PaymentFormComponent } from './components/payment-form/payment-form.component';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeGuardService } from '../../shared/guards/home.guard';
import { MaterialModule } from '../material/material.module';
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgXCreditCardsModule } from 'ngx-credit-cards';

const routes: Routes = [{ path: '', component: PaymentFormComponent }];
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule.forChild(routes), MaterialModule, FlexLayoutModule, ReactiveFormsModule, NgXCreditCardsModule],
  declarations: [PaymentFormComponent]
})
export class PaypalPaymentModule {}
```

Can someone tell me how to fix the build issue

Comment: a war file? How are you generating that, can you show your build script?

Comment: @nircraft I am doing mvn install. I get this error when I build the serve side code.

Comment: Do you have `<properties>
    <angular.project.location>angular-project</angular.project.location>
    <angular.project.nodeinstallation>node_installation</angular.project.nodeinstallation>
</properties>`  and  `<configuration>
                <workingDirectory>${angular.project.location}</workingDirectory>
                <installDirectory>${angular.project.nodeinstallation}</installDirectory>
            </configuration>` in pom.xml?

Comment: This answer may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45943326/9386929

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to setup angular 4 inside a maven based java war project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45915379/how-to-setup-angular-4-inside-a-maven-based-java-war-project)

Comment: @nircraft This is a working application . There are lot of modules which are functional. Its not a set up issue

Comment: Regardless of whether the application worked previously, failure to build is a setup issue.