# Best practice to include angular site inside a Dynamic Web Project

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I'm using eclipse to build angular application (my first application), at the beginning I created my project via New->Angular Project (I have plugins installed) but later on I was asked to use a Dynamic Web Project (with WebContent Folder) and I was wondering what is the best way of doing it!

What I tried is creating a Dynamic Web Project, then from inside the folder of that project to create a new angular2 site (in parallel to Java resources using angular-cli: > ng new Angular Resources).
But I have issues with that and I'm not sure that am doing it the right way: 
[image]

The reason why I need this is because am going to use shiro for users authentication and I need to develop a RestApi as well that will be part of the same war.
Example for such a project that was done with angularJs (angular1):

[image]

Even if I locate the angular folder under WebConent (like what was done here), I'll still have errors (JSon, DTD, HTMl) in node_modules.

I found something similar to what I'm looking for, and I'm trying to do it works for me as well:
https://github.com/Angular2Guy/Angular2AndJavaEE

[how to integrate Angular 2 + Java Maven Web Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38532210/how-to-integrate-angular-2-java-maven-web-application)

Comment: Just one question: Why do you want to use Angular 2 when there is already version 5?? https://blog.angular.io/version-5-0-0-of-angular-now-available-37e414935ced

Comment: As I know the version stepped over 2.4 and announced about angular 4 which is not even a major upgrade (the router library was changed)... but will consider it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying something different. By using the maven-war-plugin as below:

```
<plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>WebContent/WEB-INF</warSourceDirectory>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>true</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

And creating a WebContent folder manually in parallel to my pom.xml

web.xml is located under WEB-INF and it contains:

```
<servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>


<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/management/*</url-pattern>
```

But still not getting my API functioning and working with the RestController that I built for that purpose.