# Angular 2 and Eclipse - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404

Tags: angular

So I am having an issue with displaying my first component in angular 2. I followed this [post to setup typescript.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35890887/how-to-get-angular2-to-work-in-eclipse-with-typescript)
I followed the 5 min quick start guide [here on Angular website](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html)
to get my first component working. I don't get an error or anything in the console but I do see loading.... in the browser. Does anyone know what I did wrong?

package.json file

```
{
  "name": "budget_calculator",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/compiler":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/core":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/http":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/upgrade":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.10",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
  }
}
```

main.ts

```
import { bootstrap }    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { Navigation } from './components/nav.component';

bootstrap(Navigation);
```

nav.component.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>Angular 2 is present</h1>'
})

export class Navigation {

}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Load libraries for Angular 2-->
        <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
        <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
        <script>
            System.config({
                packages: {
                    app: {
                        format: 'register',
                        defaultExtension: 'js'
                    }
                }
            });
            System.import('./app/main').then(null, console.error.bind(console));
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <header>
            <my-app>
                Loading.....
            </my-app>
        </header>
    </body>
</html>
```

project structure

```
node
node_modules
src
   -> main
     -> webapp
        -> node_modules
        -> app
            -> components
                - nav.component.js.map
                - nav.component.d.ts
                - nav.component.ts
                - nav.component.js
            - main.d.ts
            - main.js
            - main.js.map
            - main.ts
            - index.html
```

Javascript console error

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (app, line 0)
[Error] Error: invoke@http://localhost:8080/BudgetCalculator/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:323:34
    runGuarded@http://localhost:8080/BudgetCalculator/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:230:54
    http://localhost:8080/BudgetCalculator/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:206:40


Error loading http://localhost:8080/BudgetCalculator/app

(anonymous function) (index.html:19)
invoke (zone.js:323)
run (zone.js:216)
(anonymous function) (zone.js:571)
invokeTask (zone.js:356)
runTask (zone.js:256)
drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:474)
g (shim.min.js:8:10178)
(anonymous function) (shim.min.js:8:10300)
k (shim.min.js:8:14323)
```

Comment: First, I assume you've checked that the typescript does indeed generate the `.js` files when you build the package. Second, most likely you're getting an error inside browser console. So I suggest to use chrome and see what the error is then add it to your post.

Comment: @Hani please see edit, typescript does generate the .js files.

Comment: Also, move to RC1 as soon as you can since it'll make it easier to migrate to later RC releases or the final release.

Comment: Remove templateUrl and make it template. It should work

Comment: Second check if u are serving the 404 error paths in webserver and that its a readable folder. Try ../node_modules relative path

Comment: updated to what I have and the same errors keep occurring with ../node_modules or /node_modules. I still keep getting the 404s

Comment: @Gary you said to second check if you are serving the 404 error paths in the web server and that its a readable folder....not exactly sure what you mean by this....

Comment: Is your node folder non-servable private web folder. Check tomcat docs

Comment: Instead of just ../node_modules what I meant is check your root web folder and then use ../../../ number of times your root web folder is structured. Try this ... what you are facing is pathing issues. If you still face the issue use <base href="/"> in your first line of your head tag of main index.html page and then try with relative path of node modules.

Comment: @Gary I solved the problem but only by looking at the documentation of tomcat and how it deploys an application. I learned that it deploys whatever is in the webapp directory. WildFly server seems to deploy this way as well. I had node_modules at the root level of the project. I solved the problem by copying and pasting it into webapp and then using a relative path. I tried what you suggested above with <base> but it didn't work. Took me forever to figure this out.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543936/load-images-from-outside-of-webapps-webcontext-deploy-folder-using-hgraphi    resource I found giving me options to deploy my files and folders.....

Comment: Cheers that it is resolved

Comment: @Gary Thank You, I learned alot and that is what matters.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to map your packages `@angular/core`,`@angular/common`... etc using systemjs. Otherwise, how would it know where to find them?

create a new file named `systemjs.config.js`

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular 2 samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function(global) {
  // map tells the System loader where to look for things
  var map = {
    'app':                        'app', // 'dist',
    '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs'
  };
  // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {
    'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
  };
  var ngPackageNames = [
    'common',
    'compiler',
    'core',
    'http',
    'platform-browser',
    'platform-browser-dynamic',
    'router',
    'router-deprecated',
    'upgrade',
  ];
  // Add package entries for angular packages
  ngPackageNames.forEach(function(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  });
  var config = {
    map: map,
    packages: packages
  }
  System.config(config);
})(this);
```

Then, in your `index.html`, import the file you created:

```
<script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
<script>
  System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
</script>
```

please notice that you should remove following from `index.html`

```
System.config({
    packages: {
        app: {
             format: 'register',
             defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
    }
});
```

The code above is taken from [angular2 quick start page](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) at the very bottom of the page.

Comment: Thank You very much