# Cannot find node_modules

Tags: angularjs, node-modules

From reading around, I have a similar problem to what is stated here:

- [Angular 2 and Eclipse - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37535273/angular-2-and-eclipse-failed-to-load-resource-the-server-responded-with-a-sta)

The project structure is *(created by ionic)*:

```
- main
    - node_modules
    - www
        - js
            - app.js
        - index.html
    - package.json
```

A link to one of the files in `node_modules` looks like this *(in `index.html`)*:

> ```
> <script src="../node_modules/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker/src/js/datetimepicker.js"></script>
> ```

*WebStorm can find the file and has no complaint in the IDE*

When inspecting the network in the console, I can see it's trying to find `node_modules` in `www`.
So the route URL is `http://localhost:8100/`

The path for `app.js` is: `http://localhost:8100/js/app.js`
The path for `datetimepicker.js` is: `http://localhost:8100/node_modules/...`

So it's looking for `node_modules` within the `www` directory which I am not entirely surprised about.

Since this structure was setup by ionic and the project has just got larger, it's difficult to change the structure *(which I thought would be the most viable to do)*. But are there any other work arounds I can do to get this working?

Also, since I select to move up a directory (`..`) to look for `node_modules`, does the webapp just omit this as it knows of no other directories higher than itself?

**EDIT:**

Looking at this question, I have followed the advice given by moving the `datetimepicker.js`into `www/lib` but it's still not working. Have not attempted to use bower yet

Answer (score -1):

Open Your command prompt .Go to your project directory and run `npm Install` Hope this will solve your problem